# HQL Unique results in ManyToMany query

Tags: java, many-to-many, hql, unique

I have multi branded application.
single user can have more than one brands, almost every query in the application restrict the user by its brands.

*User has ManyToMany with Brand(s) .*

For example, I want to pull `List<Employee>` from the DB.

```
s.createQuery("FROM User user INNER JOIN user.brands brands WHERE brands IN(1,2)");//(1,2) = :brands
```

In this situation I will get the same user more than once because the User has more than one brand connected to him.

How can query the Brand without letting effect of my results without the need of distinct?

This is the User Entity:

```
    public class User  {
        @Id
        @Column(name="USER_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer userId;

        @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name="USERS_BRANDS" , joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="BRAND_ID")})
        private Collection<Brand> brands;
        ...other members
        ...getters and setters
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the keyword **DISTINCT** into your query (right after the *SELECT* keyword that must be also added):

```
s.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT user FROM User user INNER JOIN user.brands brands WHERE brands IN(1,2)");
```

Comment: Thanks! It really helped :D

Comment: the distinct is a bad idea is performance issue thanks to it additional Sort, better is to switch to Set or to enable the Hint to avoid the distinct.